# Angular 2 with handsontable

Tags: angular, handsontable

We are presently building a web 
application with Angular JS2. 
I am trying to use a 3rd party 
JQuery grid - "handsontable" - 
on some pages of this application.
 I am not able to find a way to implement 
to use this JQuery grid in Angular 2 app. 
Any advice?

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: we need some sample code to perform CRUD operation in Angular2 with Handsontable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [ng2-handsontable](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-handsontable)? There are plenty of examples in the repository.